# How to open Materialize confirmation modal when deleting something from a database

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, materialize

Currently, I have a view which shows all documents from the database.
Each one has a button which triggers the document to be deleted from the database.

Ideally, I'd like to open a modal message (using Materialize) to ensure deletion should happen.

I know that I can have a modal for each of the elements but that seems redundant and too much to add. I'd like the flow to go from:

`button -> delete`

to:

`button -> confirm -> delete`

I'd like this to happen by changing the onClick of the button to open a modal and be able to pass the action of the confirm button through

The button code currently looks like:

```html
<button
    className="btn"
    onClick={() => {handleClick(category._id);}}
>
Delete
</button>
```

The current onClick handler for each button is the following:

```js
const handleClick = id => {
  this.props.deleteCategory(id);
};
```

I'm new to React/Redux and Materialize so any help would be appreciated and if any more information is required, please let me know :)

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution myself and since I couldn't find much else online on how to do this, I thought I'd share the solution too.

So, I installed react-materialize first and created a component to hold the modal and render the modal.

I replaced the button click function with a function which updates the state of the current component like so:

```js
const handleClick = category => {
      this.setState({
        categoryClicked: category,
        modalOpen: true
      });
    };
```

I then tied the component containing the model to this state using props like so:

```js
<ConfirmDeletion
          onClickYes={null}
          onClickNo={null}
          name={this.state.categoryClicked.name}
          open={this.state.modalOpen}
          actions={[
            <button
              onClick={modalNo}
              className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat"
            >
              No
            </button>,
            <button
              onClick={modalYes}
              className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat"
            >
              Yes
            </button>
          ]}
        />
```

Note that the actions are a list of JSX elements which should be the buttons on the modal.
I also created the click event handlers to update the state (and remove from the database in the "yes" case) as follows:

```js
const modalYes = () => {
      this.props.deleteCategory(this.state.categoryClicked._id);
      this.setState({
        modalOpen: false
      });
    };
const modalNo = () => {
      this.setState({
        modalOpen: false
      });
    };
```

and just for completeness, here's the component wrapping the modal in case it's useful to anyone in the future:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-materialize";

class ConfirmDeletion extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name, open, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        id="confirmDeletion"
        open={open}
        actions={actions}
        header="Are you sure?"
      >
        <div className="modal-content">
          <p>
            Are you sure you want to do delete '{name}'? It cannot be undone.
          </p>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ConfirmDeletion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Materialize Documentation](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#!) you should follow these steps :

1- Create your modal structure. for example :

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

2- Initialize the modal :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
});
```

Note: remove `options` if you don't want to add modal options. If don't it causes an error.

3- Change `handleClick` function to open modal :

```
const handleClick => {
  //var elem = get modal element here
  var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
  instance.open();
};
```

4- Finally, call a function when user click on `agree` to delete the category. You can add `disagree` button to close modal with :

```
instance.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to leave an answer! While this works with plain JS and Materialize, I'm trying to do this from inside a React app.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm not familiar with React very well and wrote this answer as a general guide. I think you can find an exact solution whit React Materialize : https://react-materialize.github.io/#/modals

Comment: Thanks again, I was already looking in to react-materialize and have just found a solution. I've posted it as another answer if you'd like to see.